# a question on negative mean square error

Tags: sampling, small-sample, unbiased-estimator, estimators, mse

for simple random sampling,

i have calculated some mean square errors of many types of ratio estimator.

[image]

Well, i obtained negative mean square error. Is there a mistake? negative MSE is a normal thing?

Comment: Yes, you have made a mistake somewhere :)

Comment: ı added my calculation. Please look at where there is a mistake according to you? dear @JohnK

Comment: It looks like the value of $\theta$ is what's driving the estimate to be negative. Are you sure you have the correct value?  From what I understand about Prasad-Singh estimators, $\frac{1+\beta_x}{2} < \theta < \frac{1+\beta_y}{2}$, which is not true of the values you've applied to your formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must distinguish between estimates of a parameter and the parameter itself. Thus, some estimates of a positive variance component can be negative, because one random term is subtracted from another.  Here, as @Sjoerd stated, the MSE is always positive and the formula would be positive  if true values of the component  parameters were input. But you have entered *estimates* of $\beta_y$ and $\theta$, better designated as $\hat{\beta_y}$ and $\hat{\theta}$. It is unpleasant, but not contrary to estimation theory, that $\hat{\beta_y} -2\hat{\theta}$, the difference of two random variables, is negative enough to make $\widehat{MSE}(t_2)$ negative. This does *not* mean that  $MSE(t_2)$ itself is negative.

Comment: thank you. i  found my mistake. SPSS calculates kurtosis coefficient as $\beta - 3>0$ for this i need to add 3 to SPSS' kurtosis for correct MSE calculation.

Answer (score 2):

It definitely seems like you have made a mistake, as the mean squared error can not be negative. I did look at the picture that you added, but I find it hard to determine what is going on. Nevertheless let me state the MSE for you here in case you ended up with the wrong definition.

The MSE of a set of predicted (calculated) values $Y' = (y'_{0}, .., y'_{n})$ with respect to their targets $Y = (y_{0}, .., y_{n})$ is given by

MSE = $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y'_{i} - y_{i})^{2}$

I realize I am stating the obvious here, but not the square in the above formula which prevents the outcome from becoming negative.

Comment: Well, Do you know Isaki estimator and Prasad Singh 1&2 Estimators ?

Comment: I do not unfortunately, however the mean squared error is a universal concept and should be applied in the same way.

Comment: well, bias of estimator is equal to a begatuve value? Is this true?

Comment: But after this subtraction you square this difference, causing it to become always positive.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error

Comment: Thanks you, I did not realize that the name implies on positive return value :D